# 5 year old kindergarten student threatened with expulsion

Tags: pre-schooler, discipline

My 5 year old son has a rough time at his new school. He keeps running away from the teachers and doesn't do his work requested. We were told there is zero tolerance for running away, and after 2 more occasion he will be expelled.

He has not yet had time to adjust to his new school (this was his 7th day in school), and he is not getting any; either he behaves immediately or he is kicked out? Don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: Is this behavior normal for him or does he have an explanation?

Comment: Did he attend preschool and if so, what was his behavior like there?  I had a sister than ran away from school constantly, but we lived close and back then my mom just would bring her back.  She had terrible anxiety, but no one talked about that back then.

Comment: Is running away from the teachers the same as running away from the campus? I could see that if he's sneaking off the campus at 5 then it would be a huge liability for the school since they are legally responsible for him while he is there...

Comment: What is a KG student?

Comment: @TommiBrander - Kindergarten. 5 years is the typical entry for public schools, or in general any k-12 be it public or private

Comment: have you talked to him about why he's running away and the expectations of him being in class? Is he running away because he wants to see you? or be at home? or be away from someone at school?

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to, you may need to spend an hour or two a week with him at school to provide him support, discipline, and guidance during this time; gradually pulling back as the school year progresses.